# Norm and conjugate of operator on $l^p$

Tags: normed-spaces, operator-theory, conjugate-gradient

I want to solve the following problem:

> Show that for every sequence $(\alpha_n) \in l^{\infty}$ formula
> $$A(x_n) = (\alpha_n x_n), (x_n) \in l^p,$$
> gives bounded linear operator on $l^p$, find its norm and operator $A^*: (l^{p})^* \to (l^p)^*$, such that $A^*f = fA, \forall f \in (l^{p})^*$.

I proved that it is bouned operator
$$||A(x_n)||_p = (\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |\alpha_n x_n|^p)^{1/p} \leq (sup|\alpha_n|^p)^{1/p} ||x||_p \leq ||(\alpha_n)||_{\infty}||x||_p < \infty,$$
so $||A|| \leq sup|\alpha_n|$. But also,
$$ ||A|| \geq ||A(e_n)|| = |\alpha_n|,$$
where $e_n$ is sequence with 1 in $n$-th position, 0 otherwise, so  $||A|| = sup|\alpha_n|$.

I don't know what to do for the third part, how to find $A^*$.

Answer (score 0):

If $A^{*}(x_n)=(y_n)$ then $\sum z_n\overline {y_n}= \langle (z_n), (y_n) \rangle=\langle A(z_n), (x_n) \rangle=\sum \alpha_nz_n\overline {x_n}$ for all $(z_n)$. This gives $y_n=\overline {\alpha_n} x_n$. Hence, $A^{*}(x_n)=(\overline {\alpha_n} x_n)$.

[If your sequences are real sequences then you can just remove the bars on top].

Comment: How can you say $A^*(x_n)$, when $A^*$ is defined on $B(l^p, \mathbb{C})$?

Comment: @Maria $B(\ell^{p},\mathbb C)$ is identified with $\ell^{q}$. I am taking $(x_n) \in \ell^{q}$.

Comment: Oh, ok then. But I don't understand how this satisfies the condition that $A^*f = fA, \forall f \in (l^p)^*$.

Comment: That is the definition of the adjoint operator.